# Invalid context for 'super' invocation

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/pages/home.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.amber),
    home: Home(),
));
```

home.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

List todoList = [];

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  
  todoList.addAll(['Buy milk', 'Wash dishes', 'купить картошку']);
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[600],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Список делишек'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: todoList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Dismissible(
                key: Key(todoList[index]),
                child: Card(
                  child: ListTile(title: Text(todoList[index])),
                ));
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Сделал этот код, выдает ошибку:

> Invalid context for 'super' invocation.

В этой части кода

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  
  todoList.addAll(['Buy milk', 'Wash dishes', 'купить картошку']);
}
```

Не нравится слово super
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно пофиксить

Comment: Через часик-другой проверьте ответ.

Comment: Написал...хватило полчаса.

Comment: Просто потому что метод `initState` должен быть внутри класса состояния.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша ошибка гласит:

> Invalid context for 'super' invocation

Или по русски: Неверный контекст для обращения к `super`

`super` - это обращение к родительскому классу.
В данном случае подразумевается, что тот метод `initState()`, который вы написали, должен быть переопределением родительского метода внутри дочернего класса.
Вы же попытались поместить данный метод прямиком в `main.dart` без контекста какого бы-то ни было класса...Тем более что в данном случае любой класс не подойдет.

Метод `initState()` вызывается при добавлении виджета в дерево для инициализации состояния компонента. Данный метод принадлежит классу `State`.

**Документация:**
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html

Соответственно, в вашем случае нужно данный метод(вместе с предшевствующим определением списка) поместить в класс, который наследуется от `State`.
И в Вашем случае это `_HomeState`

Все что Вам нужно это переместить данный метод и список в него

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  List todoList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    todoList.addAll(['Buy milk', 'Wash dishes', 'купить картошку']);
  }
  // ...
  // Далее Ваш код
  // ...
}
```

Это все!

**Итого:**

flutter_application_1/pages/home.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List todoList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    todoList.addAll(['Buy milk', 'Wash dishes', 'купить картошку']);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[600],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Список делишек'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: todoList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Dismissible(
                key: Key(todoList[index]),
                child: Card(
                  child: ListTile(title: Text(todoList[index])),
                ));
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ответ действительно решает проблему, но слишком растянут, не думаете?)

Comment: @SergeyK. для опытного разработчика, конечно, растянут. Но опытный смог бы и сам разобраться. А неопытному, желательно, не только сказать что не так и как нужно, но и было бы неплохо показать как нужно думать, чтобы такие вопросы самому решать.

Comment: @SergeyK. чтобы с каждым ответом у пользователя вырабатывалась полезная привычка.

Comment: Этот ответ помог,  сразу понятно в чем моя ошибка.